# Edit custom fields in posts list

Tags: posts, custom-field, quick-edit

Is it possible to edit (or add) custom fields directly in posts list (/wp-admin/edit.php)?

I need to do it quickly for many posts (1000s) so editing every and each of them would take ages to accomplish.

Comment: I think this is already answered here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3140198/wordpress-sql-adding-a-custom-field-to-all-posts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use Admin Columns Pro (paid plugin with free version) to use inline edit for custom fields columns just from the WordPress posts list. It even comes with sorting and filtering for columns. You can easily add new columns with this plugin. https://www.admincolumns.com/

There are also plugins that allows you to bulk edit custom fields from the overview. https://wordpress.org/plugins/custom-bulkquick-edit/